# identically distributed random variables have the same pdf

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have read several proofs that made use of "identically distributed random variables", yet I have no clear picture and examples of what it means for two random variables to be identically distributed.
Going through related questions, I found that two random variables are identically distributed if they have the same cdf even they may not be defined on same probability space.
I'm  having a feeling that identically distributed guarantees having the same pdf. Could someone help clarify me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Associated to every random variable is a distribution function. Two random variables, even on different probability spaces, would be identically distributed if their distribution functions are the same, pointwise.

Comment: @ астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг If they have same distribution function can we conclude their probability mass functions are the same?

Comment: by definition of a distribution function, this can definitely be concluded.

Comment: Yeah, got it. Thanks